# Delayed response when changing label text (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimageview, wikipedia, lag

My issue is that when imageFound == false, it prints out the "No Results!!!" immediately, but it takes like 15 seconds for the labels text to change. I do not know why this is lagging but I need help trying i=to put it down into the range of 5 seconds or less.

Code is below...

```
if let textFieldContent = textField.text{
        do {

            try WikiFaceRec.faceForPerson(textFieldContent, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 250), completion: {(image:UIImage?, imageFound:Bool!) -> ()  in
                if imageFound == false{
                    self.faceImageView.alpha = 0
                    self.realLoadingLbl.text = "No Results Found. Check your spelling and try again."
                    print("NO RESULTS!!!!!")

                }
                if imageFound == true{
                   self.realLoadingLbl.alpha = 0
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                        self.faceImageView.image = image

                        self.faceImageView.alpha = 1
                        WikiFaceRec.centerImageViewOnFace(self.faceImageView)
                    })

                }
            })
        } catch WikiFaceRec.WikiFaceError.CouldNotDownloadImage {
            print("Wikipedia not currently open")

        } catch {
            print("error")
            self.faceImageView.alpha = 0
            self.realLoadingLbl.text = "No Results Found. Check your spelling and try again."
            print("NO RESULTS")
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

The code below with the self.realLoadingLbl.text = "No Results Found. Check your spelling and try again." is the part that takes a bit to change. And yes, once again "NO RESULTS!!!" is printed immediately.

```
if imageFound == false{
    self.faceImageView.alpha = 0
    self.realLoadingLbl.text = "No Results Found. Check your spelling and try again."
    print("NO RESULTS!!!!!")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle the `imageFound==false` case similar to the `true` case in terms of `dispatch_async`:

```
if !imageFound {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.faceImageView.alpha = 0
        self.realLoadingLbl.text = "No Results Found. Check your spelling and try again."
        print("NO RESULTS!!!!!")
        self.faceImageView.alpha = 0                      
    }
}
```